# Como buscar Entidade e Filhas numa só sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Tenho 3 classes que se relacionam da seguinte maneira:

```
class AnamnesisModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :anamnesis_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :anamnesis_questions
end

class AnamnesisQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :anamnesis_model
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
end
```

A questão é que **ao selecionar um determinado Modelo de Anamnese, gostaria que
carregasse os 3 numa só sql**, como estou usando rails como webAPI quero enviar esse objeto todo preenchido para cima.

Até o momento eu consegui fazer algo quase bom dessa forma.

```
render json: @anamnesis_model.to_json(:include => {:anamnesis_questions => {:include => :question}})
```

O problema dessa solução é q ela não faz tudo numa só sql.

(Exemplo de uma anamnese com 3 questoes)

```
    Started GET "/anamnesis_models/41" for ::1 at 2017-07-12 15:03:50 -0300
Processing by AnamnesisModelsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"41"}
  AnamnesisModel Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "anamnesis_models".* FROM "anamnesis_models" WHERE "anamnesis_models"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 41], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  AnamnesisQuestion Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "anamnesis_questions".* FROM "anamnesis_questions" WHERE "anamnesis_questions"."anamnesis_model_id" = ?  [["anamnesis_model_id", 41]]
  Question Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 61], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Question Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 62], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Question Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 63], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: Consegui aqui utilizando joins + includes.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo a leitura do site abaixo.
http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Dentro da leitura do conteúdo testei em específico com o uso de uma

> LEFT OUTER JOIN

Para executar com uma única query, utilizei o

```
eager_load
```

Boa sorte.

Comment: ok ,, vou dar uma olhada